# Simplify algorithm with Horner Scheme

Tags: c#, algorithm, polynomial-math, polynomials

I have a problem to solve the following excercise:

*Be given the special polynomial: [image]
and the input: coefficients a[n], a[n-1], ..., a[0], argument x

Create an algorithm in C# or Pseudocode which will use Horner's method to solve the special polynomial for x.*

I created an algorithm to solve default polynomial functions with Horner's method, but it doesn't work for the special function, because the exponents are squared. I don't know how to modify the algorithm to respect the squared exponents, because as far as I know, Horner's method doesn't use exponents.
This is my code:

```
        int[] a = new int[] { 0, 3, 2, 1};//a[0] - a[n]
        int n = 3;
        int x = 2;

        double r = a[n];
        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            r = r * x + a[i];
        }
        Console.WriteLine(r);
```

I'm thankful for any help!

Comment: Actually I tested it with some values and calculated it by myself with polynomial division and the results were the same as from the algorithm above...

Comment: @GiladGreen *where do you put `x` to the power of the current `n`?* nowhere: [Horner Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method#Description_of_the_algorithm)

Comment: @greybeard: I think there is double exponentiation in the last two terms as well - but removed for simplification (x to power 1 squared is equal to x & x to power of 0 squared = 1) - so it could be made generic

Comment: (This looks an *excellent* assignment: please nobody spoil it by giving an answer without "spoiler" (`>! `).)

Comment: (Much to my dismay, I seem to be able to do/code this with two multiplications per term (which I think minimal), but it looks anything but Horner.)

Answer (score 0):

### HINT 1

> 4*4 = 1 + 3 + 5 + 7

### HINT 2

> x^(4*4) = x^1 * x^3 * x^5 * x^7

### HINT 3

> a(4)*x^(4*4) + a(3)*x^(3*3) + a(2)*x^(2*2) + a(1)*x + a(0) = (((a(4)*x^7 + a(3)) * x^5 + a(2) ) * x^3 + a(1) ) * x^1 + a(0)

### HINT 5

> You can keep track of the odd powers of x by multiplying the previous odd power by x^2 on each iteration

Comment: (That's two multiplications per term: how is it *Horner*?)

Comment: I guess it depends on what you consider the essence of the Horner method.  To my mind, the essence is the nested factorisation, and so this method is in that way similar to Horner.  But I totally agree this is subjective and opinions may vary.  Can you see an alternative that would be even closer to the Horner method?

Answer (score 0):

Let me revisit *the blunt way* and [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method#Description_of_the_algorithm) to evaluate a polynomial aₙxⁿ+…+a₂x²+a₁x+a₀ in a single variable *x* at a given value *x₀*:

- just raise *x₀* to the appropriate power *k* for each non-zero coefficient *aₖ* (*k* > 1),
  multiply and accumulate these terms
- start with the "highest" coefficient; while there is a "lower" coefficient, multiply with *x₀* raised to the *difference in exponents* between the previous coefficient and the current and add the latter

Horner's method saves work because the powers *x₀* has to be raised to are (much) lower and (, for this very reason,) fewer (down to only needing/using *x₀*).

**How do you save work evaluating a polynomial with *square exponents*?**

1. re-use lesser powers in the computation of greater ones.

   - square exponents are special

     > just as neighbouring squares differ by and odd number two greater that the next lower pair, neighbouring *square powers* are an *odd power* apart

   > the next *odd power* is the current one multiplied by the square
2. evaluate from "highest coefficient" to lowest

   - to combine this with 1.,

     > have power evaluation memoized or keep powers (used) explicitly.
     >  It may be easiest to set them up upfront.

---

**Is the combination of tricks** (still) ***Horner's method*?**
You decide. (And your tutor/teacher/interviewer as applicable.)

Comment: I have no earthly way of knowing whether 2. is included/implied in what [Peter de Rivaz has been getting at](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47421205/3789665) (short of asking/discussing).